# @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()") vs http.anyRequest().authenticated()

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, configuration, authorization

What's the difference with these two different security approaches?
First one relies on configuring `HttpSecurity` object from [Spring Security](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security).
The second one relies on putting `@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")` on each method or class.

First case:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }
}
```

Second case:

`@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")` on each method/class.

First approach looks better cause you secure all endpoints at once, and using `@PreAuthorize` requires more work. But what is actual difference between those two?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to authorize all requests on WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and do the security with PreAuthorize on each service.

The advantage to use WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is to have an overview of your security access.
But the @PreAuthorize allow you to have a more fine grained security handling. For exemple, you can tell that a user have the permission to edit an article only if he has write this article.

I think in a big application, it's ok to use both.